# Grid com auto refresh html + angularJS

Tags: html5, json, angularjs

Bom tenho uma grid e ela precisa estar SEMPRE atualizada pois nela constam informações que precisam ser atualizadas dinamicamente.

Esta grid é populada com uma chama rest que me retorna um json.
Eu preciso que a grid seja atualizada assim que o json da chamada rest ter alguma mudança.

No meu caso para tratar os dados do json e colocar na grid estou usando AngularJS e populando com um ng-repeat.
Hoje estou pegando as atualizações com um setInterval de 1 segundo... mas isso não é legal, porque se tenho que colocar algum checkbox nesta grid, não vou conseguir checkar pois como atualiza de 1 em 1 segundo voltaria sempre ao estado de FALSE.

Vocês teriam alguma solução?
Não sei como os sites que "transmitem" jogos de futebol funcionam... mas é mais ou menos desse jeito. Queria saber como eles fazem para adicionar ou remover linhas da grid sem precisar dar um refresh na grid ou no scopo inteiro.

**Meu JS:**

```
 var app = angular.module("teste", []);



 app.controller("GridController", ['$scope', '$http', function (ng,
 $http) {

     ng.locations = [];

    setInterval(function() {
             $http.get("http://testechamarest.com:18888/json").success(function
 (dados) {
               ng.locations = $.map(dados, function (dev) {
              return dev;
            });

 }, 1000); ]);
```

**Novo problema:** Quando modifico o tempo de atualizações, por exemplo: coloco de 3000(3 segs) a página demora 3 segundos para abrir... no caseo atual está demorando 1 seg para abrir... minha lógica ao fazer isso deve estar toda errada... mas não sei em que eu poderia melhorar. :(

Comment: Dê uma espiada no [Meteor](https://www.meteor.com/) - acho que vai gostar.

Comment: Poxa empresa não abre https...  mas acho que teria que mudar toda a minha estrutura... não seria legal há esta altura do projeto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Respondendo minha própria pergunta!**

Fiz da seguinte maneira:

```
var app = angular.module("teste", []);

app.controller("GridController", ['$scope', '$http', function (ng,
$http) {

//Crio uma flag 'local_data'
 var local_data = null;
 ng.locations = [];

setInterval(function() {
         $http.get("http://testechamarest.com:18888/json").success(function (dados) {

        //Utilizo o stringfy para verificar se tem alguma alteração nos dados do json   para atualizar a grid, se caso tiver atualiza a grid.. se não não! :D
    if(local_data != JSON.stringify(dados)) {
            local_data = JSON.stringify(dados);

           ng.locations = $.map(dados, function (dev) {
          return dev;
        });
    }

  }, 1000); ]);
```

E é assim que resolvi o problema hehe.. não sabia do Stringify, eu simplesmente comparava as duas variáveis,  dados e a minha flag e sempre retornava false mesmo com mudanças...
transformando em Stringify eu converto meu json inteiro em uma string e assim posso comparar se há mudanças.
Obrigado comunidade!

Comment: Acho que você deveria ler os dados, comparar linha a linha e atualizar as colunas que não foram mexidas pelo usuário (em caso de campos editáveis e checkboxes

Comment: Sim seria uma boa... mas não acha que para uma checagem de 1 seg em 1 seg isso seria muito pesado? Pensando que a grid futuramente possa ter 100 linhas.

Comment: quando precisar usar um temporizador, utilize os serviços $timeout e $interval, que se adequam ao ciclo $digest do angular. é estranho que o angular consiga atualizar a tela assim.

Comment: e se o serviço suporta retorno de dados a partir de uma condição, por exemplo, "apenas se há mudanças desde data tal", a implementação seria mais elegante.

Answer (score 0):

Da uma olhada em WebSocket, o problema é que funciona somente nos navegadores mais novos e ainda é meio precario, mas acredito qeu seja mais ou menos o que vc precisa.

Com relação a sua grid, não sei como funciona a biblioteca que vc usa, mas deve ter um método que insere linhas novas ao inves de dar refresh na coisa toda

Eu uso essa biblio aqui http://www.dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxGrid/samples/15_navigation/01_pro_keymap_access.html

Bem completa mesmo na versão gratuita

Att.

Exemplo de uso

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var JSON_que_estou_usando = {};

            function WebSocketTest() {
                if ("WebSocket" in window) {
                    alert("WebSocket is supported by your Browser!");
                    // Let us open a web socket
                    var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:9998/echo");
                    ws.onopen = function() {
                        // Web Socket is connected, send data using send()
                        ws.send("Message to send");
                        console.log("Message is sent...");
                    };
                    ws.onmessage = function(evt) {
                        var received_msg = evt.data;
                        console.log("Message is received...");

                        //faz a verificação
                        if(JSON_que_estou_usando.stringify == received_msg.stringify){
                            //adiciona linhas na grid
                        }
                    };
                    ws.onclose = function() {
                        // websocket is closed.
                        console.log("Connection is closed...");
                    };
                }
                else
                {
                    // The browser doesn't support WebSocket
                    alert("WebSocket NOT supported by your Browser!");
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="sse">
            <a href="javascript:WebSocketTest()">Run WebSocket</a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Vi esse exemplo [aqui](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_websocket.htm) e so adicionei algumas linhas no metodo "onmessage". Isso deve fazer o que vc esta precisando

Espero que ajude

Comment: Mais ou menos... o que preciso é que esta grid fique escutando o json e só atualizar quando houver atualizações.

Comment: O problema agora é que websocket não roda no webview :(

Comment: Então da pra apelar para "Long Polling". Basicamente mandar uma requisição por ajax e no lado do servidor criar um laço infinito (com 1 segundo entre uma passada e outra - algo que vc consegue com o método "sleep") e so retornar quando alguma modificação ocorre

Comment: então... é uma aplicação desktop.. não há servidores :(